# How to apply custom sort to WooCommerce product loop

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, woocommerce

My client has a WooCommerce online store which currently displays his products (approx. 600) in reverse chronological order (newest first, oldest last).

The problem is that the older products are not selling because they are always at the bottom of the page and his customers very rarely scroll to the bottom of the (very long 600 products!) page.

Unfortunately, the client is not prepared to split the products into categories or onto separate pages. He is also against a random product sort fired every time the shop page is displayed.

He has however agreed to the following:

1. always display the NEWEST products at the top of the page (we already mark these using a post_meta '_product_new');
2. split the REMAINING products into two blocks (the oldest 50% and the newest 50%) and display these blocks alternately according to the current month - even months oldest 50% block first, odd months newest 50% block first.

IMPORTANT is that the post_meta marked products are ALWAYS at the top of the page.

I think it should be possible to apply a custom product sort using the 'pre_get_post' hook:

```
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'custom_vtp_shop_order' );

function custom_vtp_shop_order($q){
    if ( ! $q->is_main_query() ) return;
    if (! is_admin() && (is_shop() || is_archive) ) {

        ...do the magic here...

    }

    remove_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'custom_vtp_shop_order' );
}
```

but I'm not sure how.

This is what I need to happen:

1. Block 1: get all products with post_meta '_product_new';
2. Block 2: get all other products and sort them in reverse chronological order (newest first, oldest last);
3. Split Block 2 in the middle creating a Block 3 and Block 4;

4a. On even months (February, April, June etc) order my products by Block 1, Block 3, Block 4;

4b. On odd months (January, March, May etc) order my products by Block 1, Block 4, Block 3.

Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you will need three separate queries using WP_Query.

```
1st - products, filtered by '_product_new', sorted newest to oldest
2nd - products, sorted newest to oldest, limit to half of posts
3rd - products, sorted oldest to newest, limit to half of posts.
```

You will more than likely have to re-write the archive-product.php. I think this would be the easiest way. The code will be pretty extensive, but I can't think of any other way you would do this properly.